# Ionic / angular ngFor and click function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I recently started playing with Ionic. So I'm making an app with a sort of 'dictionary' in it. If I press a button an audio file plays a english or german translation of the dutch word. I'm working with a array in a JSON file called 'Opdracht1.json' in it there are values with the translation from Dutch to engels/german. X&Y are for rectangle positions, but that's not important! So as output I want to get an English or German word

```
[
    {"x": "365", "y": "12", "string": "steiger", "engels": "Jetty", "duits": "Der Steiger"},
    {"x": "459", "y": "65", "string": "kanaal", "engels": "Canal", "duits": "Der Kanal"},
    {"x": "117", "y": "210", "string": "Westkolk", "engels": "West lock", "duits": "Die Westkammer"},
    {"x": "503", "y": "151", "string": "Sluizencomplex", "engels": "Lock complex", "duits": "Der Schleussengruppe"},
    {"x": "488", "y": "249", "string": "wachthaven", "engels": "Ley by berth", "duits": "Der Wartehafen"},
    {"x": "510", "y": "300", "string": "autosteiger", "engels": "Car jetty", "duits": "Der Autosteiger"},
    {"x": "581", "y": "350", "string": "Zwaaikom", "engels": "Turning basin", "duits": "Der Wendeplatz"},
    {"x": "505", "y": "652", "string": "Scheidingsboei", "engels": "Separation buoy", "duits": "Die Trennungsboje"},
    {"x": "705", "y": "550", "string": "radartoren", "engels": "radartower", "duits": "Der Radartum"},
    {"x": "931", "y": "365", "string": "Kilometerraai", "engels": "Kilometer marker", "duits": "Der Stromkilometer"},
    {"x": "887", "y": "312", "string": "schip", "engels": "Vessel", "duits": "Das Schiff"},
    {"x": "960", "y": "172", "string": "tunnel", "engels": "Tunnel", "duits": "Der Tunnel"}
]
```

From a previous page, I get which language(taal) I need ('engels' or 'duits').

```
// Get taal van de vorige pagina en zet deze in taal
this.taal = navParams.get('taal');
console.log(this.taal);
```

So here is what I'm currently trying. So here do I have a for loop on the rect for clickable rectangles to play 'audio'. In the click function, am I trying to get the right item language.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 720" *ngIf="id === 'SamenwerkenOpDeCorridor'">
  <image width="1280" height="720" xlink:href="assets/imgs/maps/SamenwerkenOpDeCorridor/opdracht1.svg">
  </image>

  <rect *ngFor="let item of coordinaten" [attr.x]="item.x" [attr.y]="item.y" width="200" height="45" fill="#fff" opacity="0" (click)="clickOnArea(item.taal)"
  />

</svg>
```

So, I need to get the right language in the click function. So if I code it like "clickOnArea(item.engels)" it works, but I want it dynamic(?) somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the ternary operator.

(click)= "clickOnArea(taal === 'engels'? item.engels : item.duits)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the access the key on the object like this, future proof if you add more languages too

```
clickOnArea(Item){
    let text = Item[this.taal];

    if(!text){
       text = ""; //set default
    }
    //use the value...
}
```

Just pass `item` to the function in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simplest. You can get the property via `[]`.

`(click)="clickOnArea(item[taal])"`